# Numerical values versus exact values in GeometricTransformation

Tags: graphics3d, numerical-value, rotation, geometric-transform

I have been doing some geometric transformations in 3D. The code bellow should transform (rotate) two black lines into red and blue tubes.

At first I used exact values of coordinates and the result was not as expected since the black lines were outside of the tubes.

So I thought I used wrong transformations - I was doing on it for two days to figure out what is wrong with my transformations - to finally find out that my transformations were correct from the very first time and that it is probably problem in `GeometricTransformation` because when I used the same transformations just with numerical values instead of exact the output was correct as magic.

**Was is causing the problem here? Normally everybody expect better precision with exact values but here the opposite happened - numerical values provide better precision than exact values.**

```
Clear[a1, a2, b1, b2, graphics]
graphics = {{Red, Opacity[0.5], Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, a1}, 0.3]}, {Blue, 
    Opacity[0.5], Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, b1}, 0.3]}, {Red, Dashed, 
    Line[{{0, 0, 0}, a2}]}, {Blue, Dashed, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, b2}]}, 
   GeometricTransformation[{Line[{{0, 0, 0}, a2}], 
     Line[{{0, 0, 0}, b2}]}, 
    RotationMatrix[{RotationMatrix[{b2, b1}] . a2, a1}] . 
     RotationMatrix[{b2, b1}]]};

a1 = {2, 5, 4};
b1 = {3, 3, -(21/4)};
a2 = {-2, 3, -4 Sqrt[2]};
b2 = {3, 9/41 (2 + 17 Sqrt[2]), 1/164 (459 - 96 Sqrt[2])};
Graphics3D[graphics]

a1 = a1 // N;
b1 = b1 // N;
a2 = a2 // N;
b2 = b2 // N;
Graphics3D[graphics]
Clear[a1, a2, b1, b2, graphics]
```

[image]

Comment: I am on MMA 12.3.1 on Win10-64. The output of the two Graphics commands is identical for me, and the same as your second figure. I do see a lot of warnings about reaching reaching maximum internal precision coming from the arbitrary-precision version. Do you see those as well? What version? What OS?

Comment: I am on 13.0.1.0 and no warnings. The warnings are on both exact and numeric values?

Comment: OK I tried the same code on the cloud (13.1.0 for Linux 64-bit) and I see the difference you see. I also receive no warnings. This looks like a bug and a regression from previous versions. You should report it to [Wolfram Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/) and then come back to add the CASE number when you receive it. It may be helpful to also include the link to this question in your report.

Comment: Were the warnings caused only by exact values or also by numeric values in 12.3.1.?

Comment: Only by the exact values.